# Change list elements to a string with spaces in Prolog

Tags: string, list, recursion, prolog, swi-prolog

In Prolog, if I am taking a list such as [hello,this,is,a,sentence] as a parameter for a predicate, how do I get a return value Y such that it will return that list as a string with spaces? e.g. **[hello,this,is,a,sentence]** will return **hello this is a sentence**.

```
makesentence([H|T],Y):- % some code here
```

I was able to run through the list recursively and have Y return the same list input with this:

```
makesentence([],[]).        % base case returns an empty list
makesentence([X],[X]).      % one list element returns that element in a list
makesentence([H|T],Y):-     % a list of more than one element
    makesentence(T,Result), % recursively call function on the tail
    append([H],Result,Y).   % append the head to the rest of the list
```

But when I try to make the output without a list and with spaces I faulter. I have tried this:

```
makesentence([],'').
makesentence([X],X).
makesentence([H|T],Y):-
    makesentence(T,Result),
    append(H,Result,Y).
```

I think it has to do with the fact the `append` predicate in Prolog only deals with appending a list, but I am unsure. How would I procede? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`atom_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_concat/3) might be your ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog has a specialized built-in for that: [atomic_list_concat](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3)/3

```
?- atomic_list_concat([hello,this,is,a,sentence],' ',A).
A = 'hello this is a sentence'.
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out with the help of Daniel. To put a list into a string with spaces use `atomics_to_string/3`. In my case:

```
makesentence([X],X).
makesentence([H|T],Y):-
    makesentence(T,Result),
    atomics_to_string([H,Result],' ',Y).
```

In the line `atoms_to_string([H,Result],' ',Y).`, the first parameter is the list, the second is what I want to add in between each entry, in this case a space `' '` and the third parameter is the assignment of the output, which in my case is Y. Thanks to Daniel for pointing me in the right direction.